# Sequelize.js - Model.update() not updating associations

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am successfully using `Model.create()` passing `include` option with association and it successfully creates father and child just on singular `create()` call.

I would like to do the same on `update()`, but unfortunatelly, it just updates the main model without affecting associated child:

```
const result = await Category.update({
    ...parentData,
    child: {
       ...childData
    }
}, { include: [{ model: Child, as: 'child' }] })
```

Am I missing something here? Why is it updating just the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [the official documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update), the options do not have a `include` entry. You have to update the associated Model separately.

Comment: I saw it missing in the docs, but searching found an suggestion using include, since it didnt work I wanted to ask here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I similarly attempted the same as you have done,

This is how to update,
Write a function, in the function  first try to update the main table data/parent data after a successful updation go for the updating part of the child table/child data in the callback function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.